# How move Working Memory (WM) span task into a VR?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, working-memory

How a classic Working Memory Capacity task that can be translated into a VR Task?

I want to study the effect of WM Load into resource allocation in a VR Environment.
To do so I would like to move a WM span task into VR.
I am working on the evaluation by ERP of the resources allocated to the VR environment when manipulating sensory immersion and the task should resemble a WM operation span task.

But I am struggling with finding in literature paradigms in VR to study working memory span.
Wich might be an ecological translation of a WM span Task in a VR environment i.e. developing a task that resemble an ecological situation but that still involves attention and memory interference (according to Conway et al. (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/BF03196772.pdf))

Thanks to everyone will dedicate attention to this question!

Comment: Dear Alice, thank you for your message. VR is a useful tool to investigate memory functioning in daily-life-like environments. VR allows creating naturalistic situation and increasing their ecological validity as compared to classical experimental or neuropsychological tests. VR also enables interaction with the environment, for example by controlling displacements, which increase the feeling of immersion in this environment which I am interested in for the purpose of my PhD.

Comment: Sorry for this. I am doing ERPs research and I want to evaluate if involuntary ERPs elicited by task-irrelevant sounds are affected by the degree of immersion in a VR-WM task? I want therefore manipulate the audiovisual properties of the VR environment and see if this manipulation affects the amplitude of ERP components evoked by task irrelevant auditory stimuli.

Answer (score 2):

I just searched for "working memory virtual reality" and the first result was a recently standardized virtual reality assessment of attention and working memory in adults ([https://doi.org/10.1080/23279095.2019.1646745](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Gema_Climent/publication/334560743_A_new_Virtual_Reality_tool_Nesplora_Aquarium_for_assessing_attention_and_working_memory_in_adults_a_normative_study/links/5d4864eca6fdcc370a7f7331/A-new-Virtual-Reality-tool-Nesplora-Aquarium-for-assessing-attention-and-working-memory-in-adults-a-normative-study.pdf)).  Hope it helps!

Climent, G., Rodríguez, C., García, T., Areces, D., Mejías, M., Aierbe, A., ... & Feli González, M. (2019). New virtual reality tool (Nesplora Aquarium) for assessing attention and working memory in adults: A normative study. Applied Neuropsychology: Adult, 1-13.